# Passing multiple duplicate properties in multiple LitElement

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, lit-element

One can pass down properties to another **`LitElement`** this way:

```
myRender(myParameter) {
  return html`
    <my-element-one .propertyOne=${myParameter.somePropertyOne}></my-element-one>
  `;
}
```

I have dozens of properties that I need to pass to multiple elements.

```
myRenderOne(myParameter) {
  return html`
    <my-element-one 
      .propertyOne=${myParameter.somePropertyOne}>
      .propertyTwo=${myParameter.somePropertyTwo}>
      ...
      .propertyHundred=${myParameter.somePropertyHundred}>
    </my-element-one>
  `;
}

myRenderTwo(myParameter) {
  return html`
    <my-element-two 
      .propertyFive=${myParameter.somePropertyFive}>
      .propertySix=${myParameter.somePropertySix}>
      ...
      .propertyFifty=${myParameter.somePropertyFifty}>
    </my-element-two>
  `;
}
```

How can I pass common properties without duplicating dozens of lines of code?

Comment: Related lit-html issue with some code that might be useful: https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/issues/923

Answer (score 0):

Pass them via Javascript.

Setting a custom property:

```
myElement.myProperty = myArrayOfProperties
```

Calling a custom method:

```
myElement.setProperties( myArrayOfProperties)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would groups all those properties in a `commonsProps` object:

```js
const commonsProps = {
  propertyOne: somePropertyOne,
  propertyTwo: somePropertyTwo,

  [...]

  propertyOneHundred: somePropertyOneHundred,
}
```

And use standard LitElement databinding:

```html
<my-element-one .commonsProps=${commonsProps}></my-element-one>
<my-element-two .commonsProps=${commonsProps}></my-element-two>
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: I also have some parameter, I am not sure how to pass it in object. Edited question with detail.

Comment: Couldn't you simply pass the .commonProps=${myParameter} to all the elements, more or less like in my answer?